# Using "what" with "alleged to be"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[image: The Moral Foundation of Politics by Ian Shapiro]

Can someone explain what does this part:

> as distinct from what their bases in reason may or may not be alleged to be.

means?
I don't understand what does "what" belongs to. I have two variants:

1 - **what their bases in reason may or may not be**

2 - **what their bases in reason alleged to be**

But in either case I don't understand the full meaning of the sentence.
If my question is not clear please ask me to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase (2) doesn't make sense. What something is *alleged to be* means what people claim that it is. So the meaning of the passage that puzzles you is:

as distinct from what people may or may not claim that their bases in reason are.

*their* referring to *identification and commitment* (I think! It's quite a difficult sentence even for a native speaker to follow).

Comment: I see it does fit to the context. Thank you very much.